# Simulate button click in a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jsf

i'm trying to code an application for Android that fills up a form in a webpage,submits it and parse results to show them. I'm using javascript to fill up the fields and then call the form's action, but it doesn´t work. I have studied the web html code, but i believe it uses JSF to display and handle the form. Is there any way to simulate the submit button click just as if i press it physically? In case anyone want to take a peak in the code, web url is http://www.transportedecantabria.es. The fact is i'm not a big expert in web programming and i'm a bit lost :).Thx and sorry about my english

**EDIT:** I've also tried this:
`javascript:var elementToGet = "frmBusqueda:j_id29";
var form = document.forms["frmBusqueda"];
var button = form.elements[elementToGet];
button.click();`

But it keeps reloading the web, not giving me the submit result

Comment: The code on that page is very long and hard to follow.  It's much better to write a minimal testcase and share that.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Stewart, the fact is that i don't own the page. It's a goverment web and i just want to be able to use it from my android app. Thx for caring anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to call the `click()` method on the button object to fire it, though it would probably be better to call the `submit()` method on the form object.

Comment: Hi Martin. I've tried both things. Calling submit() method just reloads the page. I believe that jsf knows that there was not a physical click so it doesn't really submit form's fields

Comment: What about the `click()` method? That's all I can think of that would work.

Comment: I've tried it in a IE windows like this: javascript:document.getElementsByName('frmBusqueda:j_id29').click() and it throws me this error: object does not accept this property or method

Answer (score 1):

This code made the trick:

`javascript:var elementToGet = "frmBusqueda:j_id29";
var form = document.forms["frmBusqueda"]; 
var button = form.elements[elementToGet]; 
button.click();`

Thx all for your help

Comment: You should accept Martin answer as you're using his exact idea - he just didn't give the full code..

Comment: Ok. My first question here, didn't know exactly what to do. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.forms
```

to retrieve the form elements within the current document.

If you want to submit the first form:

```
var firstForm = document.forms[0];
firstForm.submit();
```

Comment: I've tried that too o-richie-nal.Calling form.submit() just reloads the page. Thx anyway :)